# Why do RAMMAP's total RAM usage of processes/mapped-file not even remotely add up to the total Memory usage in User Counts?

Tags: memory, operating-systems, task-manager, process-explorer, memory-usage

- RamMap: **User Counts**

[image]

- **Processes**

[image]

- **File summary**

[image]

In RamMap, the memory usage in first image is right.
However, when I tried to add up all the Active memory, and the 2nd image and 3rd image doesn't match the first tab. Why?